# Short-cut to select tag

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resharper

What is the short cut to select XAML in block ( including closing and opening tag).

From below sample, I should be able to select all content using short cut.

```
<GroupBox Header="To Date" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold">
    <StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Environment: Visual studio Version 2010 with re-sharper 7.0

Comment: Shortcut in visual studio right? Also which version of Visual Studio are you using? Adjust your tags accordingly.

Comment: @OmegaMan, I am using VS 2010 with re-sharper installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> would select the current declaration. Each time you press it, it would select the next containing declaration.
(It's a resharper shortcut: `Resharper_SelectContainingDeclaration`)

Comment: Cool. This is what I wanted. However, do you know how to reverse it. I mean deselect the selection made through ctrl+shift+[.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Open up the window `Document Outline`. From there you can highlight the grid via a mouse click and make it invisible in design mode (the eye icon) or change the grid by doing other right click options.

---

To select in the editor do the following

1. Collapse the target element.
2. Double click in the click zone (to the left of the collapse uncollapse + -) next to the collapsed element.
3. UnCollapse the top level element and that element and its children are selected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the proposed option is to select control or control group in designer. What I wanted is in the XAML editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Extend/Shrink selection](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Extend_Shrink_Selection.html) (select necessary keyboard shortcuts layout)